How to manually create a PDA Anchor account with a discriminator?
I had several occasions where I needed to create a new account within an instruction, and using Anchor's init feature was blowing up my stack.
This can happen in the case of an Initialize instruction where I had to set up multiple accounts, or just a random instruction with a lot of accounts and constraints that were already consuming a significant portion of the stack memory.
I have seen that sometimes people were splitting their instructions into two just to mitigate this issue.
But this is suboptimal.
The question is: how can we do it manually without Anchor init in vanilla Solana, keeping in mind that we need to initialize the discriminator on our own so that later we can use this account like any other Anchor-initialized account?

I couldn't find a fully working solution for this anywhere, so I'm sharing my solution here in case it might be useful for someone.
As an example, I will use the classic Initialize instruction, where we are setting up config/PDA accounts for a program.
First, pass this account for initialization as a mutable UncheckedAccount:
Account definition:

#[account]
#[derive(InitSpace)]
pub struct DeliveryPriceConfig {
    pub tx_cost: u64,
    pub max_delay_between_updates: u32,
    pub last_update_timestamp: i64,
}

impl DeliveryPriceConfig {
    // discriminator bytes plus struct size
    pub const LEN: usize = 8 + Self::INIT_SPACE;
    pub const SEED_PREFIX: &'static [u8] = b"delivery_price_config";
}

Initialize instruction:

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub owner: Signer<'info>,

    #[account(
        mut, 
        seeds = [ DeliveryPriceConfig::SEED_PREFIX ],
        bump
    )]
    pub delivery_price_config: UncheckedAccount<'info>,

    ...
}    

Than in the handler code for your instruction manually initialize it:
use anchor_lang::{prelude::*, system_program, Discriminator};

pub fn handler(ctx: Context<Initialize>) -> Result<()> {
create_delivery_price_config(&ctx)?;
...
}

fn create_delivery_price_config(ctx: &Context<Initialize>) -> Result<()> {
    let signer_seeds: &[&[&[u8]]] = &[&[
        DeliveryPriceConfig::SEED_PREFIX,
        &[ctx.bumps.delivery_price_config],
    ]];

    create_and_init_pda(
        &crate::ID,
        &ctx.accounts.owner,
        &ctx.accounts.delivery_price_config,
        DeliveryPriceConfig::LEN,
        signer_seeds,
        DeliveryPriceConfig::DISCRIMINATOR,
    )
}

pub fn create_and_init_pda<'a>(
    program_id: &Pubkey,
    payer: &AccountInfo<'a>,
    pda_account: &AccountInfo<'a>,
    space: usize,
    signer_seeds: &[&[&[u8]]],
    discriminator: [u8; 8],
) -> Result<()> {
    let rent_lamports = (Rent::get()?).minimum_balance(space);
    invoke_signed(
        &system_instruction::create_account(
            payer.key,
            pda_account.key,
            rent_lamports,
            space as u64,
            program_id
        ),
        &[
            payer.clone(),
            pda_account.clone()
        ],
        signer_seeds
    )?;

    let mut pda_data = pda_account.data.borrow_mut();
    // pda_data can be larger than the discriminator, so we just take a slice of equal to size of the discriminator.
    pda_data[..discriminator.len()].copy_from_slice(&discriminator);

    Ok(())
}

Later, you can use this account like any other Anchor account, and it will be correctly serialized/deserialized.
